# VBScript RegExp IE8 Addons inventory script

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-8, vbscript

IE8 Add-ons export script (vbscript)

I am attempting to parse a text file that matches a string "DllName" and then writes everything following DLLName will be written to a text file.

What would be the regular expression for this?

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

`objRegEx.Pattern =`

Comment: And what is your question? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: objRegEx.Pattern = .............What would be the regular expression pattern to just find the first few letters of "DllName" and then write everything following DllName to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "\bDllName.*"
```

`\b` is a word boundary that ensures there is not a word character before.

`.` matches any character (but no newline character)

`*` quantifier, matches the previous expression (here: any character) 0 or more times